# ng-if inside ng-repeat always returning true

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-table, angularjs-ng-if

I am creating a table with data from the Premier League. I am trying to use `ng-if` to check if the home team won and if so add a cell saying "Home team won"

**HTML**

```
<div ng-if="data.full_time_result: === 'H'">
    <td>Home Team Won!</td>
</div>
```

However this is adding the "Home Team Won!" to every row even when the full_time_result isn't 'H'.

Here is a link to the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/EjDGFsMyGpXho675meAJ?p=preview).

Also, what would be the recommend way to achieve this functionality? Having lots of `ng-if` blocks probably isn't the best way to go about this.

Answer (score 5):

You can not have `div` inside table element `tr` directly, it would make an invalid html. To make it working you could wrap that `div` in `td` tag.

**Markup**

```
<td>
    <div ng-if="data.full_time_result === 'H'">Home Team Won!</div>
</td>
```

[**Working Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/mlNMZwGPsV2SSKfUTyIS?p=preview)